# Python 2.7, Excel.csv getting specific columns &...?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv

**Sorry**, guys If there is a post similar or exactly like this. I'm new to programming/coding and just couldn't find a similar post.  What I'm trying to do is a script that *takes a keyword/input from the user* and from that keyword the program will find all columns in the excel.csv data. Then make a *copy of the column/s to a new excel file*. This is with the intention of working with large excel files. Is there any tutorials or a place where I can find even tips/hints/Examples of how to do this? Thanks for your time and comprehension.

Again is just:

1. Name of the file to be read.
2. keyword which identify columns to be saved/copy/cut.
3. Create new file then paste + truncate?

   (**Anything close to this or a tutorials/examples would be truly appreciated.**)

Sincerely,
A novice.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Hope this will give you some idea...